ARM Assembly (Data Transferring Instructions)- confusion caused by the identicalness of instructions and that about auto-indexing
When coping with multiple data transferring, Arm Assembly provides some instructions for us to use, like stmfa, stmfd, stmia, stmib... are for storing multiple data to memory; while ldmed, ldmea, stmdb, stmda... are for loading data from memory.
My 1st question is: why do ARM provides pairs of instructions that do the same thing(stmfa v.s stmib,etc), isn't that redundant?

My 2nd question is: why don't we limit the stm and ldm instructions to use auto-indexing? I think it make the coding a lot more simpler
Consider the following scenario:
When we do data transferring, that's say we want to store the value of current fp and lr, the regular way to do this is by doing:
stmfd sp!, {fp, lr}

(Suppose that this is a very simple assembly program that doesn't recursively jump to other procedures and we don't use the registers r0 through r3, so there's no need to store other register's value into the memory)
After doing some simple stuff, we just need to restore the value of fp and lr back to the corresponding registers and give the control back to the system:
ldmfd sp!, {fp, lr}
bx lr

But when it comes to the instructions that don't use auto-indexing, it will then become something like this:
stmfd sp, {fp, lr}

// some codes here
// this is a very simple program

ldmea sp, {fp, lr}

This is not that intuitive to compared to the ones that use auto-indexing, so why is that?
I would really appreciate it if someone could eliminate my confusion.

Yes, it's redundant, but one of the two sets of indexing suffixes may express your intention more clearly in certain circumstances.  If you're implementing a stack, then the (full/empty)(ascending/descending) versions are preferred, since they describe the structure of the stack itself, and are the same with both stm and ldm.  But if you're just accessing sequential elements in a buffer, (increment/decrement)(before/after) more clearly express what exactly is happening to the pointer register.

Note that these are just different mnemonics for the same instructions.

stm/ldm with the stack pointer would normally have auto-indexing.  but these instructions can be used with other base registers, any base register.  so for example if you want to do a 64 bit load or store before the strd and ldrd came along, or 4 words or 8 words or 5 words or....

a 64 bit load or store does not have to be 64 bit aligned, can be 32 bit aligned with an stm/ldm, you may get a performance hit but these are 32 bit based instructions...they are not simply push/pop instructions, they are store multiple and load....multiple....
